# How can I create a live ISO for a customized operating system?

Tags: iso, sabayon

I would like to create an ISO file (which can be used to create a live CD or USB or as a primary controller for a VirtualBox machine) for a customized version of Sabayon Linux I have created on a VirtualBox Virtual Machine (VM), but I do not know how. This customized version of Sabayon is based on Sabayon SpinBase (which is the version of Sabayon specifically designed for creating new spins of Sabayon) and uses the Moksha window manager as its default desktop environment. My host machine, if relevant, (as I imagine creating an ISO will require me to install some extra software) is Sabayon Linux too.

My Linux knowledge is that of a novice-intermediate user, so please phrase your answer accordingly (like avoid using phrases that only an experienced Linux user is likely to understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Live image creation is a big work

Live image have to detect and conforme to hardware **while** booting!

You have to pre-install all drivers and firmwares...

It's a not so simple job!

<s>I know http://live-systems.org where you could customize your ***Debian Live***</s>... Unfortunately, *live-system.org*'s server don't exist anymore. It was a CGI drived GUI to `live-build`.

You may found this Debian package by simply run:

```
apt install live-images live-build
```

This package will let you configure and build your own ***live*** ISO or USB.

But it's ***Debian***, not ***Gentoo*** based, so not ***Sabayon***.

Comment: Looks like the domain of the link provided has been squatted by some business unrelated to Linux.